# Handling multiple TCP connections on the only one socket in server

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming, tcpserver

Please assume that we can distinguish packets of different TCP connections from each other, if so then can we accept multiple TCP connections on the only one socket in server side? I know that the server binds on a socket and when accepting new connection assigns a new socket to new connection. Would I override **ACCEPT** systemcall?

Comment: So you want *one* socket in the server to receive all data from all connections? Like is done for UDP? Then no it's not possible in TCP, as it's a connected protocol, each connection is a separate entity.

Comment: Why? Everything you've mentioned is already done by TCP, and it's done in the form of a separate socket per accepted connection. Why do you think you need to reinvent the API?

Comment: @ EJP. Think that I want to handle a lot of connections with minimum delay so it's better to handle all of connections by one socket instead of creating a socket for each of the connections but ACCEPT systemcall returns separate socket for each accepted connection. Because of that I think I should override the ACCEPT systemcall!

Comment: @MSH - you will break TCP.

Comment: @MSH - did you ever get a definitive answer?  I agree it would be nice for a server managing 10000's of low rate connections not to have 10000's of sockets.  Or, possibly modern systems can handle many sockets just as efficiently as an application could demultiplex its own data?

Comment: Though I guess the TCP stack must demultiplex the connections anyway, so as long there is efficient method to deliver notifications (epoll or kqueue) shouldn't be any reason not to use 10000's of sockets… unless you are planning to replace entire TCP stack.  e.g., http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html

Answer (score 0):

> Please assume that we can distinguish packets of different TCP connections from each other

You can't assume it. There are no 'packets' visible to the application over a TCP connection. A TCP connection provides a byte stream. You can't guarantee that the next thing you read will be say a message header telling you which client the message is from.

Comment: Packet boundaries are not visible, but addr,port information is.  There is no reason a TCP socket could not work just like a UDP socket, delivering "next n bytes from addr,port", where n is arbitrary (unlike UDP).

Comment: @user1055568 '`addr.port` information' is not visible to an application over a TCP connection, other than via `getpeername()`, which applies to the socket and therefore the entire connection. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I was just saying that is how the Berkley socket API is designed, nothing to do with whether the TCP protocol defines application level packet boundaries.